# jquery validation addmethod not defined

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Im trying to add a custom validation method to jquery validation plugin. When I try to attach the rule to an element I receive an error "uniqueTicket" not defined.

Here is my add method:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("uniqueTicket", function (value, element, param) {

    var data = {
        ticket: value,
        reservation_id: $("#reservation_id").val()
    };

    if (value.length > 3) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '/ticketaudits/validateTicket',
            data: data,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (msg) {
                //If username exists, set response to true
                response = (msg == 'true') ? true : false;
            }
        });
    } else {
        response = false;
    }
    return response;
},
    "Ticket is invalid or already used");
```

This is being called within the same document ready function as the validation. My validation is:

```
$('#myForm').validate({
    debug: false,
    ignoreTitle: true,
    onkeyup: false,
    rules: {
        ticket: uniqueTicket
    }
});
```

I've followed a number of examples for this but don't understand the problem. Does this mean there's an error in my addmethod?

Comment: Also show the relevant _rendered_ HTML markup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your `input` contains `name="ticket"`,

this:

```
rules: {
    ticket: uniqueTicket
}
```

should be this:

```
rules: {
    ticket: {
        uniqueTicket: true
    }
}
```

Comment: Brilliant - so frustrating to miss it staring at your face!